# How to swap div of html by mouseover on javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to implement content of text on html which can switch to function of drag and drop when there is mouse pointer.

content of "A"

```
<p>drop here</p>
<div id="dropbox" ondragover="f_dragover(event)" ondrop="f_drop(event)">
</div>
```

content of "B"

```
<p>Hello World!!</p>
```

Content of "B" needs to be switched into content of "A" when there is mouse pointer on same location.
I should implement function of swap only using html,JavaScript,css.

Comment: what did you try? and what goes wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:
html:

```
<div id="toreplace">
  
  <p>drop here</p>
  <div id="dropbox" ondragover="f_dragover(event)" ondrop="f_drop(event)"></div>
  
</div>
```

javascript:

```
let swap = () => {
  
  let replace = document.querySelector("#toreplace");
  
  let b = "<p>Hello World!!</p>";
  
  replace.innerHTML = b;
  
}
```